# Replacing values in vector by 0 except for sample and looping this

Tags: r, loops, vector, sample

I have a vector, in this case "dist_SLA" for which I want to do the following:

- I want to take samples of increasing sizes, from size = 1 until all values of "dist_SLA" are sampled (so size = 1, size = 2, size =  3, ..... size = "dist_SLA"). --> Ill call the sample vectors sample.i
- Then I want to transform all the sample vectors "sample.i" to new ones using this method:  The vector should be transformed so that all values from "dist_SLA" that were not sampled in sample.i are replaced by 0, so that it gives me a vector which includes the sampled values and zeros. I'll call the new vectors "sp.i"
- Lastly, I want to make a list which combines all calculated R-squares of lm of all different transformed vectors "sp.i" and "dist_SLA" (So R-square of sp.1 with "dist_SLA" + R-square of sp.2 with "dist_SLA", etc)

I have tried the following:

```
  dist_SLA <-  c(1, 4, 9, 3, 4, 6)

  for (i in 1:NROW(dist_SLA)){
    sample_[i] <- sample(dist_SLA, size = i )
    sp_[i] <- ifelse(dist_SLA == sample_[i], yes = sample_[i], no = "0")
    lm_[i] <- lm(dist_SLA ~ sp_[i])
    fit_[i] <- summary(lm_[i])$r.squared
    }
```

But this gives me a few problems:

- The "ifelse" function gives me a vector in which all values that are identical to the value(s) of the sample won't get replaced by 0 in "sp_1". I therefore want a vector in which only the sample value(s) is/are not replaced by 0 but the others are.
- The loop does not work in this way but I cannot figure out how.

How can I fix this?

Comment: *Ill call the sample vectors sample.i*. This is not what you are doing with `sample_[i] <- sample(dist_SLA, size = i )`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following does what you want.
Note that you don't need the `sample.i` vectors, only the r-squared  values will be saved. so you only have to have a vector where to save them.

```
set.seed(3520)    # Make the results reproducible

dist_SLA <-  c(1, 4, 9, 3, 4, 6)

n <- length(dist_SLA)
fit <- numeric(length(dist_SLA))

for (i in seq_along(dist_SLA)){
  smpl <- sample(n, size = i)
  sp <- numeric(length(dist_SLA))
  sp[smpl] <- dist_SLA[smpl]
  lmi <- lm(dist_SLA ~ sp)
  fit[i] <- summary(lmi)$r.squared
} 

fit
#[1] 0.6480000 0.0200000 0.1739130 0.7667327 0.8711111 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set.seed(123)
sample_ <- sample(dist_SLA, size = 3)
sample_
[1] 4 3 6
dist_SLA <-  c(1, 4, 9, 3, 4, 6)
```

Then this will give you

```
dist_SLA==sample_
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Whereas using %in% gives:

```
dist_SLA %in% sample_
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

And

```
ifelse(dist_SLA %in% sample_, dist_SLA, 0)
[1] 0 4 0 3 4 6
```

So your loop, depending on what you want to save for later usage could look like

```
set.seed(123)

dist_SLA <-  c(1, 4, 9, 3, 4, 6)
lm_  <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(dist_SLA))
fit_ <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(dist_SLA))

for(x in 1 : length(dist_SLA)){

  sample_ <- sample(dist_SLA, size = x)
  spi     <- ifelse(dist_SLA %in% sample_, dist_SLA, 0)
  lm_[[x]]  <- lm(dist_SLA ~ spi)
  fit_[x] <- summary(lm_[[x]])$r.squared
}
```